# 0-1 Laws in Probability

Tags: probability-theory

We have in probability the Kolmogorov 0-1 Law and the Blumenthal 0-1 Law and I am wondering whether there are any other relatively general results like these which state that, under some hopefully mild conditions, some event happens with probability 0 or probability 1. Does anyone know of any more such theorems?

I know also of a theorem in percolation theory which states that if $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathbb{P}_p)$ is the probability space in which $\Omega$ is the set of all graphs on vertex set $\mathbb{Z}^d$, and $\mathbb{P}_p$ is the probability measure under which an each edge between neighbouring sites in the lattice is present independently with probability $p$, and $A$ is an automorphism invariant event in $\mathcal{F}$, then $\mathbb{P}_p(A)\in\{0,1\}$.

A google search on the matter was not very helpful due to 0-1 laws being more well known in logic.

Comment: $0$-$1$ laws shouldn't be trivial or mild, quite the contrary, at least from an intuitive point of view. Indeed, for an event to have probability zero or one it is necessary and sufficient that such event should be independent of itself (this is a tautology). Having said that, do you know Hewitt-Savage 0-1 law? I believe this is amongst the most general results (and even then the hypothesis essentially implies that the events are independent of themselves by assuming that $\mathscr{F} = \sigma(\mathscr{F}_0)$ with the events in $\mathscr{F}_0$ independent of themselves).

Comment: Have you seen [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero%E2%80%93one_law)?

Comment: Thanks @angryavian that's exactly the kind of thing I was looking for